# jQuery event.keyCode 0 when Swedish keys å, ä and ö are pressed

Tags: jquery, internationalization, keyboard-events

I have an html form with a lot of text fields that all take only one character (think crossword puzzle). When a letter is entered in an input field, I use jQuery to jump to the next one. This works fine, except for the Swedish characters åäö (other international characters are probably affected too).

I bind an event listener to the keyup event, and use the event.keyCode and event.which to determine if the pressed key was a letter (if it was any special key, the events passes untouched).

The problem is that when I press å, ä or ö, both event.keyCode and event.which are 0. When I examine the event object in Firebug, I can't find any attribute that seems to hold the key code.

The code looks like this:

```
    var crossword = $('article.crossword');

    crossword.bind('keyup', function(event) {
        var target = $(event.target, crossword);

        if (target.hasClass('crossword_letter_input')) {
            var pressedKey = event.which ? event.which : event.keyCode;
            var target_value = target.val();
            var target_tabindex;

            // Regular alphanumeric keys have keyCodes between 48 and 90.
            if (pressedKey >= 48 && pressedKey <= 90 && target_value.length) {
                target_tabindex = parseInt(target.attr('tabindex'));
                $('input.crossword_letter_input[tabindex=' + (target_tabindex + 1) + ']', crossword).focus();
            }
        }
    });
```

I use the keyup event in order to move focus after the character has been entered into the text field.

If you know of any jQuery plugin or vanilla JS that could replace this completely, that would also be a solution.

EDIT: I have made a temporary (and ugly) fix by inserting the following else if:

```
    // å, ä and ö reports keyCode 0 for some reason.
    else if (pressedKey === 0 && target_value.length) {
        target_tabindex = parseInt(target.attr('tabindex'));
        $('input.crossword_letter_input[tabindex=' + (target_tabindex + 1) + ']', crossword).focus();
    }
```

This way, I simply suppose that if the event.which and event.keyCode was both 0, and the length of the value in the field is greater than 0, focus should be moved to the next input. Supposing stuff without knowing doesn't feel great though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keycode is 0 for the right alt on keyboard. When you type a letter that requires use of this alt key you get 0 from ket code. There are other keys that also give the code == 0 (eg. the windows key on FF on linux)

This code (taken from jquery example and changed a bit) produces what should be enough:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<input id="whichkey" value="type something">
<div id="log"></div>
<script>$('#whichkey').bind('keypress',function(e){ 
  $('#log').html(e.type + ': ' +  e.which );
});  </script>

</body></html>
```

when you type it gets triggered for alt+letter twice - once with which==0, next with which==correct code for the letter.

eg.

Where I live alt+a produces ą and goes the right code in an event after the one with 0.
Keydown was only sent once with the 0 code in the same situation.

codes:

```
alt==0
a==97
ą=261
```

Comment: Absolutely brilliant! Thanks!

Comment: Mike McCaughan suggested it first, but he didn't think it was promising. I just knew the code must be sent somehow, but it probably was some event throttling that stopped it from being triggered by jquery while alt ws pressed.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery automatically normalizes `event.keyCode` and `event.which` into `event.which` so you may be losing something by renormalizing on `event.keyCode`. Take a look at the example on jQuery's API documentation page for [event.which](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/), which will show what the key code is for characters entered.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I tried the demo, but get the same result there. When I press å, ä or ö keys, I get "keydown: 0". :(

Comment: Huh. You might try to capture the `keypress` event instead of the `keyup`, but it doesn't look promising. See http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html for an interesting investigation on how browsers recognize keyboard events. It appears that most browsers at this point do not handle anything other than ASCII key codes. Unicode code points are coming in the DOM Level 3 Events specification, but no released browser implements those fully. IE9 beta is closest (!).

Comment: That's bad news indeed... I'll put a bounty on this one for a while, just in case anyone might have any workarounds...

Answer (score 1):

The characters that you mentioned often times require two key presses to be entered.  This does make keypress detection problematic.  So instead of focusing on the key pressed, how about looking at the side effect of pressing a key by looking directly at the value that is in the input field?

```
$('input')
    .bind('keyup', function (e) {
        var t = $(this), // the current input element
            value = t.attr('value'),
            new_value = value.slice(-1); // last char only (if any)
        t.attr('value', new_value);
        t.select(); // highlight the text of current element 
                    // or jump to the next... whatever you want
    })
    // optional select on focus to make things consistent if you .select() above
    .bind('focus', function () { 
        $(this).select(); 
    });
```